# facebook graph api field image width

Tags: php, facebook, object

How to get source value if its height and width is >= something

MY WORK: i using facebook graph api to get these values.. its output as json object.. that's not the problem i need to get only one link means source value that its width has to given value.

or if its possible to give condition in facebook graph that will be easier

My code:

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$this->post[id]}?fields=images&access_token={$this->user->token}";
$url = file_get_contents($url);
$link = (array)json_decode($url);
```

suppose think i want to get source value and its height should be > 420...

```
Array
(
    [images] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [height] => 1152
                    [width] => 2048
                    [source] => https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-snc6/256375_463526207001195_392636722_o.jpg
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [height] => 540
                    [width] => 960
                    [source] => https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash4/427440_463526207001195_392636722_n.jpg
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [height] => 405
                    [width] => 720
                    [source] => https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash4/s720x720/427440_463526207001195_392636722_n.jpg
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [height] => 337
                    [width] => 600
                    [source] => https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash4/s600x600/427440_463526207001195_392636722_n.jpg
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [height] => 270
                    [width] => 480
                    [source] => https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash4/s480x480/427440_463526207001195_392636722_n.jpg
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [height] => 180
                    [width] => 320
                    [source] => https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash4/s320x320/427440_463526207001195_392636722_n.jpg
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [height] => 101
                    [width] => 180
                    [source] => https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/427440_463526207001195_392636722_a.jpg
                )

            [7] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [height] => 73
                    [width] => 130
                    [source] => https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/427440_463526207001195_392636722_s.jpg
                )

            [8] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [height] => 73
                    [width] => 130
                    [source] => https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s75x225/427440_463526207001195_392636722_s.jpg
                )

        )

    [id] => 463526207001195
    [created_time] => 2012-08-19T16:22:21+0000
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the width and height parameters in the graph api call to retrieve the picture in alternate sizes.
eg - https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?width=300&height=420 
Please refer to this blog post for more details - 
 https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/22/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/